# MySQL Select next 2 rows greater than time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a database that has stored time values for a train schedule. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bahn_hausen` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=132 ;
```

Now I want to select the next two rows after now():

```
SELECT time FROM bahn_hausen WHERE time > now() LIMIT 2
```

The Problem is that when now is > than last time today (23:45:00), there is no row selected. However, I want to select the next 2 values of course (00:15:00 and 00:45:00). This only works correctly when now() is >= 0:00:00

**[edit]**For clarification: The problem I am having is that SQL doesn't recognize 00:15 to be greater than 23:45.

How do I do this?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost there.  You just need an `order by`:

```
SELECT time
FROM bahn_hausen
ORDER BY time > now() desc, time
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It still assumes that 0:15 is smaller than 23:45.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the method CURTIME() or DATEDIFF(...) > 0

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time

Comment: I don't see how this could eliminate my problem. The problem I am having is that SQL doesn't recognise 0:15 to be greater than 23:45.